# How to display a different set of cell values based on a value in a different cell

Tags: excel, vba

What I'm trying to do in Excel using VBA is to have a cell that the user enters a value into, and get the sheet to bring up a set of values in a range of cells based on the value input. So for example, let's say we have a profiling spreadsheet, as below:

[image: Sam profile]

But then the user wants to view/edit Adam's profile, so he changes the value in `A1` to "Adam":

[image: Adam's profile]

And the spreadsheet automatically changes the values in `B3:B7` to Adam's details, which the user would be able to edit, and go back to Sam's and then back to Adam's, and find that the details are still saved (same with Sam's profile if he were to edit that one).

I've been trying to do something like this for an Excel spreadsheet using VBA code, but couldn't figure out how. If anyone could give me some pointers on how I could do this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most likely this is easily doable with formulas, no VBA required.

Comment: Have a sheet that acts as a data table. In the display sheet, have a `worksheet_change` event that monitors A1. Whenever a new non-blank value is entered into A1, search the data table for a matching name, grab all values in the same row as the matched name like `rMatch.EntireRow.Cells(x).Value`. Put the values one by one into the display sheet. Done!

Comment: @Toddleson has given you a VBA way to go that would work, but unless there is a lot more complexity that you aren't describing in the question, I would seriously consider @BigBen's comment about using formulas, particularly `=VLOOKUP()` or `=HLOOKUP()` (or maybe `=XLOOKUP()` or `=MATCH()` which I've used but am less familiar with).  If you're committed to a VBA approach, go that way, but if it can be done **easily** with formulas, often my spreadsheets with VBA cause trouble for the mortals at work who can't read what god has written. ;-)